# Как убрать кнопку

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress

В сайте на вордпрессе в мобильной версии имеется кнопка меню.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю как ее убрать и оставить только меню (без кнопки). Html код в данной теме изменить нельзя, только css и jquery файл. В идеале должно быть так. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

display:none; кнопке задай тогда

Comment: Тогда и меню не будет показывать. Оно появляется только при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: Читай тему наследования.

Answer (score 1):

На меню вешай display:block;
на кнопку которую надо скрыть display:none;

Comment: Помогло. Спасибо!